# AutoCloseable "resource leak" warning for factory created instances?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocloseable

These "resource leak" warnings I'm getting in Eclipse for `AutoCloseable`s seem to be a life-saver.

However, how do I get them to work for factory created instances?

For example (`a` works, but `b` doesn't):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // a) This emits a warning
    new AutoCloseable() {
        @Override
        public void close() throws Exception {}
    };

    // b) But this doesn't!
    newResource();
}

public static AutoCloseable newResource() {
    return new AutoCloseable() {
        @Override
        public void close() throws Exception {}
    };
}
```

Is there an annotation I can stick on `newResource()` or something I can do to let the compiler (or is it Eclipse?) know of the ownership change?

Comment: Intellij can generally warn if some return values are disregarded. This could help as you would than have to assign the value locally.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9624018/1266906

Answer (score 2):

The Neon Eclipse documentation on "resource leak" detection explains what is going on; see ["avoiding resource leaks"](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-avoiding_resource_leaks.htm). It states:

> ### Ownership / responsibility
>
> The above diagnostics basically assume that a method that creates an
>   instance of a resource type is also responsible for closing this
>   resource. However, some resources will be shared among several
>   methods. Here the analysis makes the following assumptions:
>
> 1. If a method returns a resource to its caller, it is not responsible for closing; no problem is reported.
> 2. If a resource is stored in a field, no single method is considered as responsible for closing; no problem is reported.
> 3. If a method obtains a resource via a method call rather than by a new expression, it may or may not be responsible; any problems are
>      only flagged as potential resource leaks.
> 4. If a resource is passed as an argument in a method call or constructor call, the current method may or may not be responsible;
>      any problems are only flagged as potential resource leaks.

Point #1 explains why there is no "resource leak" warning for the `return` statement in the `newResource` method.

Point #3 explains why there is no "resource leak" warning for the `newResource()` call.  At best, it would be a "potential resource leak" warning.  Either you have those warnings disabled, or the previous warning is inhibiting it.

---

Q: Is there an annotation to tell Eclipse about transfer of resource ownership?

A: The Neon Eclipse documentation doesn't mention any such annotation.  (And it does go into detail about the annotations for null checking!)